# Change Node and NPM version on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need specific node and NPM version for my ruby on rails app. Elastic Beanstalk platform i am using is ruby 2.3 with passenger. It comes pre deployed with node and npm but the vesions are not what I require.

```
[root@ip-172-31-35-134 configuration]# /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node -v
v4.6.0
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-134 ~]$ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/npm -v
2.15.9
```

Any idea how to change the default vesions?

Answer (score 0):

put it in .ebextensions

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_nodejs.sh":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash

        . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh

        set -xe
        EB_NODE_VERSION="v8.9.4"

        file="/etc/elasticbeanstalk/baking_manifest/node_installed_$EB_NODE_VERSION"
        if [ -e $file ]; then
            echo Node.js has already been installed. Skipping installation.
        else
            EB_TARBALL_URL=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tarball_url)
            EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k node_install_dir)

            MACHINE_TYPE=`uname -m`
            if [ "$MACHINE_TYPE" = "x86_64" ]; then
                ARCH=x64
            elif [ "$MACHINE_TYPE" = "i686" ]; then
                ARCH=x86
            else
                echo "Unknown architecture."
                exit 1
            fi

            mkdir -p $EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR
            curl -L https://nodejs.org/dist/$EB_NODE_VERSION/node-$EB_NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.gz | tar zxf - -C $EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR
            ln -sf $EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR/node-$EB_NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH/bin/node /usr/bin/
            ln -sf $EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR/node-$EB_NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/
            ln -sf $EB_NODE_INSTALL_DIR/node-$EB_NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH/bin/npm /usr/bin/
            echo $(date) >> "/etc/elasticbeanstalk/baking_manifest/node_installed_$EB_NODE_VERSION"

            rm -rf /home/webapp/.npm/
            rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/node_modules/
            npm cache clean --force
            rm -rf /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v6*
            rm -rf /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4*
        fi

        mkdir -p /home/webapp
        chown -R webapp:webapp /home/webapp
        mkdir -p /var/app/support/.npm_global
        npm config set prefix /var/app/support/.npm_global
```

Comment: Many thanks; it really worked and helped me in updating node and npm.

Comment: but the original issue for which i was trying to update node is still there

  > npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js


  > @ ensure-node-version /var/app/ondeck/client
  > check-node-version --package

  sh: check-node-version: command not found

  npm ERR! Linux 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v7.8.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "ensure-node-version"
  npm ERR! node v7.8.0
  npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
  npm ERR! file sh

Comment: change node version in the script         EB_NODE_VERSION="v7.8.0"

Comment: that I have already done; and after running the deployment via elastic beanstalk, i am still getting the error at the check-node-version :(

Comment: and i am getting following error as well now
  nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/var/app/support/.npm_global"

Comment: Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v7.8.0` to unset it. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

Comment: i think nvm is not installed there. if prefix is not needed, delete the last line in the script

Comment: This answer's a bit old now. This answer is more up-to-date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334515/rails-6-0-2-with-node-8-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk