# Rails 6.0.2 with Node 8 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-6

The newest version of Rails, 6.0.2, comes with a package.json that uses rails/webpack version 4.2.2 which requires Node 8.

The prevailing internet wisdom seems to be to use RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=true and instead use an `.ebextension/fix_rails_6.config` file containing

```
commands:
  02_download_nodejs:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -"
  03_install_nodejs:
    command: "yum -y install nodejs"

container_commands:
  19_precompile:
    command: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

(full file https://gist.github.com/lettergram/7384acdc3a157579a1692cc0af09d33a)

However, this results in an error `Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 6.17.1`...

How can I get the precompile to use the Node 8 that was already installed?

Answer (score 3):

I got this working just now with the following (found [here](https://gist.github.com/mattlima/096aa95f1779c809a628cca2f53fd28e)):

```
# .ebextensions/fix_rails_6.config

commands:

  00_remove_node_6_if_present:
    command: "/bin/rm -rf /var/cache/yum && /usr/bin/yum remove -y nodejs && /bin/rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource* && /usr/bin/yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum"
    ignoreErrors: true
  01_download_nodejs:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -"
  02_install_nodejs:
    command: "yum -y install nodejs"
  03_install_yarn:
    command: "sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && sudo yum install yarn -y"
  04_mkdir_webapp_dir:
    command: "mkdir /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  05_chown_webapp_dir:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  06_chmod_webapp_dir:
    command: "chmod 0744 /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  07_chmod_logs:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/current/log/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  08_create_log_file:
    command: "touch /var/app/current/log/production.log"
    ignoreErrors: true
  09_chown_log_production:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/log/production.log"
    ignoreErrors: true
  10_chmod_log_dir:
    command: "chmod 0664 -R /var/app/current/log/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  11_update_bundler:
    command: "gem update bundler"
    ignoreErrors: true
  12_chown_current:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/current/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  13_chmod_current:
    command: "chmod 0755 -R /var/app/current/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  14_chown_current:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/ondeck/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  15_chown_current:
    command: "chmod 0644 -R /var/app/ondeck/"
    ignoreErrors: true

container_commands:

  16_install_webpack:
    command: "npm install --save-dev webpack"
  17_precompile:
    command: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

I had to make a change to ensure `node 6` was removed and `node 12` installed instead adding `&& rm -rf /var/cache/yum` to the end of the `00_remove_node_6_if_present` command as it was still installing `node 6` with the original.

However I encountered more grief with the NGINX proxy after this, which I fixed by changing the webpacker `public_output_path` to `assets` instead as I decided to use webpacker for everything rather than sprockets.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't verify your solution. After struggling with Beanstalk for a while, I finally getting it to work and then constantly encountered more problems with it later on, I finally abandoned it for Heroku. YMMV. Hopefully someone else finds your answer useful though!

Comment: Yeah fair enough I'm starting the think the same way myself, I'm surprised by just how flaky EB is, Heroku by comparison is a dream.

Comment: I'm also surprised there's so few people working with Rails on EB. You'd think there's be tons of people writing tons about it. But it really seems like not.

Comment: Yeah other than Heroku I wonder what everyone else uses for Rails now? I really wanted EB to be good, Heroku doesn't have data centres here while AWS does. Was going to use it for some projects, but supporting something like this in production makes me nervous...

Comment: I would probably recommend just using raw EC2 then. You can get a very long way using bigger and bigger EC2 instances as your needs grow. It's a bit more work than Heroku but less then EB. Cause even with EB, you still have to set up your DB, your DNS, active job, action cable, caching, logging, etc etc.

Comment: @SimonL.Brazell   Digital Ocean is a dream compared to AWS, people might be using that.  I've worked on Rails projects hosted there, deployed using capistrano.

Comment: @RandallCoding unfortunately Digital Ocean also doesn't have data centres in my country so for projects that require that it's a no go, and for all others I just use Heroku as I'm familiar with it.